# iOS how to add radio buttons

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

[image: I would like to add in my ViewController something that should look identical with the first item of this picture (Simple passcode + radio button). Do I need to use a UITableView and define the hearder and the footer for this? Can someone provide me some examples of how to start and work with this?]

I would like to add in my ViewController something that should look identical with the first item of this picture (Simple passcode + radio button). Do I need to use a UITableView and define the hearder and the footer for this? Can someone provide me some examples of how to start and work with this?

Comment: I suggest to you to create a UITableViewController (or your custom class inerrited from UITableViewController), create a UITableViewCell with a basic UILabel and UISwitch, and that's it. Make the outlet connections, and voila :). Here an old example, but you have the idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4585840/how-to-create-a-uitableviewcell-with-a-uiswitch-and-get-the-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom UITableViewCell with a UILabel on the left side of the cell, and a UISwitch on the right side.

Register the custom cell class with the table view and a cell identifier and then customise it as you would any other cell.

```
static NSString *const CellIdentifier = @"customCell";

/**
 *  Called after the controller’s view is loaded into memory.
 */
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.tableView registerClass:[CustomCell class] forCellIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

/**
 *  Asks the data source for a cell to insert in a particular location of the table view.
 *
 *  @param  tableView                   A table-view object requesting the cell.
 *  @param  indexPath                   An index path locating a row in tableView.
 *
 *  @return An object inheriting from UITableViewCell that the table view can use for the specified row.
 */
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Simple Passcode";

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: If the class where I am using the CustomCell is a UIViewController, where I have UITableview, when using [_tableView register...] I get an error message no visible interface UITableView declares the selector register. How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution is to set up a UITableViewController using static layout in interface builder.

[image]

Then set up your table however you want it to look:

[image]